About path-independent line integrals, I think people are explaining it backwards?
First of all, this is summary of what I have learned so far in my calculus II class:
(1) If domain is simply connected -> Irrotational implies Path independent 
(2) If domain contains 'hole' in it -> Possible exceptions may arise
(2) is OKAY because I know few concrete examples -- I know how to perform and evaluate actual line integrals. But (1) is still dubious because I can't still find book/texts that shows proof of (1) that goes like " … this property A is all what causes possible exceptions in (2) and since this property B implied by simply connected gracefully frees us from any concern about property A thus we conclude this proof is complete …".
unless proof of (1) that includes reasons why am I safe from cases that I learn about (2), I can't even believe (1) though each proofs of (1) are logically sound. You can prove A is essential for B by showing not A can possibly result not B? I don't think it should be allowed in strict language of mathematics.
Let alone Green's theorem, this makes things worse!

The proof of $(1)$ is most easily seen as a direct application of Stokes' Theorem, which usually comes up later in a class on multivariable calculus than conservative vector fields, so it's typically hand-waved off as "it just works." I don't believe that any reasonable textbook would claim that $(1)$ is proven simply because all known exceptions have domains which are not simply-connected. Rather, they are attempting to build the intuitions of young students to extrapolate relevant common features of the counterexamples, and then confirm this on grounds of authority

The typical proofs of (1) are a bit more sophisticated than a beginning multivariable calculus class can support (because we need to work rigorously with what simple connectivity means). But if you assume that you're on a star-shaped (or convex) domain, there are plenty of proofs you can understand, many on this site. Here is one.

@infinitylord That opens Pandora's box wide open. How do you prove carefully that a curve in a simply connected domain bounds a smooth, oriented surface?
